# How to extract sub-List, tuples and digits from List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list (**CustomerID**), which contains **List, digits, Tuples** and I need to perform below tasks:

a. extract sub list [1,2],[2,3],[4,6],[6,9], Tuples (1,2,3) (76,5,3) and Digits and insert into separate list.
b. access elements from List and Tuple eg: [1,2] elemt0, elemt1

```
CustomerID = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,6],[6,9],3,7,2,(1,2,3),(76,5,3)]
```

Please help me.

I tried below code but can't access the elements and says new list(lstEle) is not List type.

```
while(a <= len(lst)-2):
    lstEle.append(lst[a])
    a +=1
```

Comment: a hint. check the type of each element, and build logics based on the type. Essentially, the type of element dictates which list it goes into.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
CustomerID = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,6],[6,9],3,7,2,(1,2,3),(76,5,3)]

list_of_lists =[]
list_of_tuples =[]
list_of_elements =[]
for item in CustomerID:
    if type(item) is list:
        list_of_lists.append(item)
    elif type(item) is tuple:
        list_of_tuples.append(item)
    else:
        list_of_elements.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isinstance`

**Ex:**

```
CustomerID = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,6],[6,9],3,7,2,(1,2,3),(76,5,3)]

lst = []
tpl = []
dgts = []
for i in CustomerID:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        lst.append(i)
    elif isinstance(i, tuple):
        tpl.append(i)
    else:
        dgts.append(i)
print(lst)
print(tpl)
print(dgts)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 6], [6, 9]]
[(1, 2, 3), (76, 5, 3)]
[3, 7, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an alternative, I think this is a great case to use functional programming. You could easily use `filter` but it's also interesting to try it with `reduce`.

```
from functools import reduce

CustomerID = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,6],[6,9],3,7,2,(1,2,3),(76,5,3)]

reduce(
  lambda acc, cur:
     { **acc, type(cur).__name__:[cur] + acc[type(cur).__name__] },
  CustomerID,
  {'list':[], 'tuple':[], 'int':[]}
)
```

Maybe at first, it looks a bit awkward but once you understand `reduce`, you see that it's pretty elegant (at least that's my opinion ;).
Also it generalizes quite well to new cases (e.g. new types) without much changes...

PS: I didn't understand the last part of your question...